# When is SQL Server as a distributed caching mechanism worthwhile?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, distributed-caching

I have 2 web servers, and I'm running into an issue where I need to prematurely expire (remove) a cached item. Since I'm currently using `IMemoryCache`, a `Remove(key)` call only removes the cached item from one server. I don't have the ability to leverage Redis, Nache, etc. but the app is already using SQL server. I can easily set up distributed caching with a cache table, but it seems counter-intuitive because what I'm caching is user data that I don't want to hit the database for on every call (e.g., I cache 50 items of user data every 5 minutes which has cut down on 500 trips to the database). Is there something I'm missing which would make using SQL server as my distributed cache backend actually beneficial?

Comment: Which SQL Server version? SQL Server 2014 and later have in-memory tables. In any case there are *many* types of caching. With response caching, the server caches the generated HTML output so it doesn't have to produce it again. Using a database for caching makes sense in this case. It would also make sense for user data that's expensive to produce.

Comment: Accessing cache data is very different from accessing application data too. With cache data, you just look up a key and read/write a blob piecemeal. There are no locks across records or tables, no blocking across connections. Using in-memory tables reduces contention even further as they don't need to acquire locks at the page or table level

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2017. I am caching user information such as who is in what role. The system does not have many special-access roles so there are only 50 users and that data only changes maybe once a month. I want to instantly remove the cache key when the security is edited (which works, but it only happens on one server). Using distributed cache seems to be the best way to do this, but performance-wise I'm not seeing it.. I'll investigate in-memory tables as that makes sense to me.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think your comment should be the answer. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.0) - important note: When SQL Server is used as a distributed cache backing store, use of the same database for the cache and the app's ordinary data storage and retrieval can negatively impact the performance of both. We recommend using a dedicated SQL Server instance for the distributed cache backing store.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are having the typical problem of cache invalidation and expiry. You can use a grid-cache for distributed caching (e.g. Redis, Hazelcast) but it doesn't solve the invalidation problem. You may want to consider vendors like ScaleArc or Heimdall Data. They provide the caching logic. You choose the storage of choice (in-memory, Redis etc.) and it handles query caching and invalidation. The is SQL Server blog on it: https://www.itprotoday.com/industry-perspectives/reduce-sql-server-costs-heimdall-data-caching

Comment: This does not answer my question, but I do appreciate that link!